# SQL Subqueries within Subqueries

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have a music database with a table Tunes. Each Tunes record contains an `ArtistID` and `Rating`.

What I want to do is retrieve all of the unique `ArtistID` fields (easy enough) plus a column indicating that some of the Rating values for each of the Artist's tunes are nonzero.

I can make a query to return 0 or 1 to determine if any of an Artists tunes haven't been rated as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM ( 
    SELECT ID FROM Tune WHERE ArtistID=a AND Rating < 1 LIMIT 1 
)
```

The above query would return a "SomeUnrated" true or false (1 or 0) value.

And.. I can make a query to return all the unique artist IDs that are featured in the Tunes table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Artist.ID, Artist.Name
FROM Artist JOIN Tune ON Artist.ID=Tune.ArtistID
```

How can I combine these two queries so that I a list of values as follows:

```
Artist.ID  Artist.Name  SomeUnrated
```

I am using **SQLite**. Is this an example of a "correlated" subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your values that are unrated are `null` (which proper db design would dictate), then you can sum your ratings.  A number + `null` = `null`.  So you would get your false.

```
Select 
  Artist.ID, 
  sum(rating) as SomeUnrated
from
  Artist 
  join Tune on Artist.ID = Tune.ArtistID
group by
  Artist.ID
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9ae00/7)

I do recommend `null` as the unrated value, if you still want a zero, you can coalesce the `null` to `0`.

<sub>*I left name off because I forgot it in the schema, simply add it to the select and group by</sub>

EDIT:

I believe this is the solution based on comments.

```
SELECT
  Artist.ID, 
  Artist.Name,
  SUM(Tune.Rating) AS SomeUnrated,
  COUNT()
FROM
  Artist 
  JOIN Tune ON Artist.ID = Tune.ArtistID
GROUP BY
  Artist.ID
```

Comment: No, as written, this would find SUM(rating) for a *single artist*. The OP seems to be after an indication of whether there are any unrated artists *at all*.

Comment: @AndriyM, my interpretation of OP's question is that he wants to be able to distinguish between an artist that has all his tunes rated, or only partially rated.  Perhaps the `SomeUnrated` name is misleading

Comment: @paqogomez: Thanks - its given me something else to think of but I'm afraid it won't give the required result. 'Rating' can be +ve, 0 or -ve. The only way your solution would work would be if it returned a 1 or a 0 if the SUM(Rating) was equal to the total number of Tune records belonging to the Artist.ID. I can work this out programmatically or in steps but I really need a single SQL statement and my SQL isn't that hot. :)

Comment: @SparkyNZ `+ve`? is that a string value?  Can you modify the fiddle to give the proper schema?

Comment: @paqogomez: No, its an integer. +ve values are 'liked' tunes, -ve values are hated tunes and zero are neutral (unrated).

Comment: I believe "+ve" stands for "a positive [numeric] value".

Comment: @paqogomez: I just added a COUNT() before the FROM keyword and that will give me the count of all of the tunes for each artist. I could compare the SUM() with the count but I'm not sure at the moment if that would work.. been a long day!

Comment: @AndriyM, thank you, that helps. :) Sparky I think i understand better, I'll modify my query.

Comment: @SparkyNZ, To clarify, you are looking for artists whose tunes do not all have ratings, correct?

Comment: @paqogomez: Yes, that was the original way I approached this. I thought it would be optimal since I could bail the subquery as soon as a <= 0 rating was found. (That's how I would have done this in code with a loop).

Comment: @paqogomez: I think we have a solution though.. At the end of the day, I want to know are all tunes for an artist 'liked' or are some not. By comparing if SUM() >= COUNT(), that will give that answer. I will just have to implement and test to see how optimal it is. This is on an Android device so performance is everything :)

Comment: @SparkyNZ Try looking at this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9da53/3  It gives a list of all the artists that have some or all of their tunes unrated.

Comment: @paqogomez: I don't think that second fiddle will work. From what I can tell, it will only return unrated artists. I need to know whether they have been rated. Please see my Edit on your answer if you are able. You may not be able to see it until it has been peer reviewed, but I would have thought you would have been a 'peer' in this case.

Comment: @SparkyNZ, I am.  I modified it a bit to make more sense in the context of my answer

Comment: @SparkyNZ, to be clear, my second fiddle shows completely unrated artists AND partially unrated artists.  To tack on the rest, you could use a union.

Comment: Re: `A number + null = null` – that is correct only when you are actually doing the sum with a `+`. For the purpose of `SUM()`, on the other hand, [`null` is just ignored](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d41d8/1376).

Comment: @paqogomez: Awesome - really appreciate your help on this one.

Answer (score 2):

As the first step towards the final query, you can replace DISTINCT with a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
    Artist.ID,
    Artist.Name
FROM Artist
JOIN Tune ON Artist.ID = Tune.ArtistID
GROUP BY Artist.ID, Artist.Name;
```

The results would be same as with DISTINCT but now you will be able to incorporate the other piece of information into the query. You will not need that to be a subquery but you *will* need a conditional to go with it, so...

```
SELECT
    Artist.ID,
    Artist.Name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Rating < 1 THEN 1 END) AS SomeUnrated
FROM Artist
JOIN Tune ON Artist.ID = Tune.ArtistID
GROUP BY Artist.ID, Artist.Name;
```

Alternatively you could calculate the same result with `MAX()`:

```
SELECT
    Artist.ID,
    Artist.Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Rating < 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SomeUnrated
FROM Artist
JOIN Tune ON Artist.ID = Tune.ArtistID
GROUP BY Artist.ID, Artist.Name;
```